# Magento cli command not executing

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I am trying to execute the php bin/magento cron:run command in my gitbash but its not executing like all the other commands i use (list, setup:upgrade etc.)

It keeps staying like this;

[image]

As you can see i am using Xampp 7.0.15. I also tried to add --group="groupname" but gives me the same.

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Are other Magento commands working fine?

Comment: They are, but i found the problem. I was using xdebug and somehow this specific command will not run if xdebug is listening (phpstorm), so i turned it off and this fixed it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD

```
goto C:\xampp7\php // Wherever your PHP is located.
```

Now run the command like

```
php C:\xampp7\htdocs\mymagento2\bin\magento cron:run
```